# Tutorial on setting up Redis with MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, redis

I am looking for a simple tutorial on how to setup Redis on AWS to connect with my MYSQL db on RDS. I can find a simple tutorial on how to launch a node but nothing on what to do after. Does it cache the entire DB? Can I configure a Redis node to cache a specific query result? In other words how can I have this node filled with information in cache and how can I access the cache from my php web services on an EC2 instance.

Comment: I think your idea of what Redis does is a bit flawed. Redis does not connect directly to MySQL. I see you tagged your question with PHP, so if you are trying to cache results from MySQL queries in Redis you would have to use some PHP library to accomplish that.

Comment: So how does it work then all tutorials seem to point to such a solution. Anywhere where I can get a better example of Redis cacheing

Comment: Link to one of these tutorials you are talking about if you want us to help you understand it.

Comment: As Mark said, caching, in Redis or Memcached, has to be done by the app. It is not automatic. The main pattern is: Lookup something in cache, if it doesn't exist, repeat the lookup in your primary store and save the result in the cache for next time.

Comment: @SFO great that is what I was expecting it to do actually so instead of my webservice going to the db constantly it can go to Redis cache. Thats the tutorial I am looking for how to have my php web services to query a db and keep the result in Redis Cache and serve that query up from cache when it is called on.